# Converting JSON to CSV File : String Indices must be Integer error whereas I already used json.loads()

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I want to extract data from API and store that in form of table. So, I extracted data in JSON form and now trying to store it in .csv file but while doing so I am getting the error: **String Indices must be integer**

The code I have used is as:

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv
f = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KORD:9:US/observations/historical.json?units=e&startDate=20140703&endDate=20140704&apiKey=742a31ced27a477045')
json_string = f.read()
x = json.loads(json_string)
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))

# For CSV Headers
f.writerow(["obs_id", "obs_name", "temp", "valid_time_gmt"])
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["observations"]["obs_id"],
                x["observations"]["obs_name"],
                x["observations"]["temp"],
               x["observations"]["valid_time_gmt"]])

f.close()
```

If you see, I have already used json.loads(), then ideally here this issue should not come. Please let me know what I am missing here.

JSON data format is as follows:

```
{ 
  "metadata": { 
    "language": "en-US",
    "transaction_id": "1484310885350:-90975020",
    "version": "1",
    "location_id": "KORD:9:US",
    "units": "e",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1484314485,
    "status_code": 200
  },
  "observations": [
     { "key": "KORD", "obs_id": "KORD", "obs_name": "Chicago/O'Hare", "valid_time_gmt": 1404453060, "day_ind": "N", "temp": 61 }, 
     { "key": "KORD", "obs_id": "KORD", "obs_name": "Chicago/O'Hare", "valid_time_gmt": 1404456660, "day_ind": "N", "temp": 60 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: errors in your for-loop: `for x in x`. I think you need to rename your `x` to `data` on line 6.

Comment: And there is a second error as well. You should probably set `data` to `json.loads(json_string)['metadata']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json data is a nested dictionary-list-dictionary structure. 
If you iterate `for x in x` you will get the keys (strings) at the first level of the data (e.g `metadata`), and you cannot use another string (e.g. `obs_id`) as an index for a string object.

The loop below will iterate the observations and write them to the csv file.

```
for o in x["observations"]:
    f.writerow([o["obs_id"],
                o["obs_name"],
                o["temp"],
                o["valid_time_gmt"]])
```

`x["observations"]` will get a list of dictionaries. `for o in ...` will iterate each element of this list. And because each `o` is another dictionary, you can refer to its keys.

The full code of your example with: 
1) better csv file handler
2) call to external API substituted with example data inline
3) proper iteration of the data

```
import json
import csv

# import urllib2
# f = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KORD:9:US/observations/historical.json?units=e&startDate=20140703&endDate=20140704&apiKey=742a31ced27a477045')
# json_string = f.read()

json_string = """
{ 
  "metadata": { 
    "language": "en-US",
    "transaction_id": "1484310885350:-90975020",
    "version": "1",
    "location_id": "KORD:9:US",
    "units": "e",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1484314485,
    "status_code": 200
  },
  "observations": [
     { "key": "KORD", "obs_id": "KORD", "obs_name": "Chicago/O'Hare", "valid_time_gmt": 1404453060, "day_ind": "N", "temp": 61 }, 
     { "key": "KORD", "obs_id": "KORD", "obs_name": "Chicago/O'Hare", "valid_time_gmt": 1404456660, "day_ind": "N", "temp": 60 }
  ]
}
"""
x = json.loads(json_string)

with open("test.csv", "wb+") as fw:
    f = csv.writer(fw)

    # For CSV Headers
    f.writerow(["obs_id", "obs_name", "temp", "valid_time_gmt"])
    for o in x["observations"]:
        f.writerow([o["obs_id"],
                o["obs_name"],
                o["temp"],
                o["valid_time_gmt"]])
```

Comment: Sorry, but @karol could you help me with your above comment. Are you suggesting to pass key, value pairs under key - observations as dictionary and then iterating them to populate the .csv ? How basically we gonna do that ?

Comment: For the example data you have provided, the code in the for loop will do the job. I changed a bit the explanation in the answer.

Comment: I have used the iteration in your fashion, but still I am getting the same issue at "for o in x["observations"]. I guess, it is still recognizing x["observations"] as string instead of integer.

Comment: I added one more clarification (source of the error) and a full code that I tested